# Strange "transparent look" windows in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, transparency

I'm using an MSI Modern 15 laptop and there's an issue that has been appearing very often. Some windows, such as system windows, chrome pop-up windows or even the file searcher show the same problem. They appear transparent when there's another window behind them. This specially happens when there is a video in the window that is in the back, but sometimes it happens without this happening.

I would upload a screenshot as evidence, but when I take one it looks fine in the png file. That's why I'm uploading a picture which was taken with my phone.

[image: Problem with transparency above a youtube video]

If anyone knows how to solve it, tell me please.

Comment: The fact that any screenshot makes it look normal tells you it is a hardware problem. You can try reinstalling the displaycard driver but it might be something on a hardware level.

Comment: I've seen that it only happens when the Intel UHD driver is installed. So I've uninstalled it, but it reinstalls automatically. How can I avoid it from reinstalling?

Comment: Try uninstalling and directly afterwards install a different driver. either from the same manufacturer but different date (newer or older) or from a different place. For example if you install the driver from your laptop brand, install the one directly from intel.

Comment: This happens to me as well (Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga gen. 3)